# ASM program to get the sum of integers 1 to 10 in R16

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

develop an ASM program to get the sum of integers 1 to 10 in R16.. 
hope someone can help total newbie

Answer (score 2):

since the task does not require to actual calculate the sum the answer may be pretty easy:

```
LDI R16, 55
```